# JsonCpp: how to convert an unordered_map to Json::Value

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

How to convert an `unordered_map` in C++ to `Json::Value` in JsonCpp?

For example I have a

```
unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map;
```

and I would like to convert it to Json::Value:

```
Json::Value myJson = ConvertToJson(map); // not a real code
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Beware, Json.cpp uses a map to store data. So your unordered_map will be ordered inside the Json::Value.

Here it is:

```
Json::Value ConvertToJson(std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map)
{
    Json::Value json;

    for(auto& element : map)
    {
        json[element.first] = element.second;

    }
    return json;
}
```